# Vagrant stalling on boot

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I am trying to get a virtual machine working with Vagrant. Everything seems to run fine and it begins to unpack/install all the needed files. But every single time it just stalls when I get to this point.

==> default: Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11) ...

Here is a screen shot of what is going on:

[image]

I shut down the virtual machine and booted it back up. I can ssh into it but nothing seems to work. By this I mean there is no psql, no SQLAlchemy. These, among other things, are supposed to be set up in the VM. It seems as if it halts before installing the necessary software.

I've tried vagrant destroy and reinstalling, downloading a new image in case that one was corrupt and I tried reinstalling Vagrant. I am running Vagrant 1.9.5

Comment: How long have you left Vagrant to do its thing? Building the initial VM can take some time.

Comment: I left it for over an hour the first time

Comment: the image is fine but your provisionning is taking long or maybe hangs, we'll need more details on the provision being run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're provisioning with shell commands. I'm guessing that there's some sort of install prompt that's coming up and demanding some sort of user interaction / response. Because vagrant's handling the provisioning behind the scenes, you can't respond to the prompt and the install is not continuing.

You should be able to fix the issue by editing your `Vagrantfile`. As a guess, it looks like `grub-pc` is causing the issue (there's actually a `grub-pc` command prompt in the image you shared). See if you can figure out which package is installing `grub-pc`. If you're lucky, the problem can be solved by piping in a `yes` along with the install command (which will automatically answer yes to all install questions). This looks something like `yes | sudo apt-get install grub-pc`. If grub-pc is being installed as part of another package, you'll need to do some educated guessing to figure out which package is installing it and adding the `yes | apt-get` pipe to that install line (or just add the pipe before every install line).

This being said, I ran into an issue when I was installing the Java SDK on vagrant, where Oracle was demanding I accept their terms of use before the install would complete and a yes pipe wouldn't solve the issue. I was able to fix it by searching the web for "silent java sdk install via command line". If you can figure out which package is causing the issue, and a yes pipe isn't enough, searching for how to "silently" install that package via command line should help.

### UPDATE

As you can see in a comment on this answer

> Unfortunately a yes pip didn't do the trick this time but a quick
>   search on how to "silently" install grub led me to this.
>   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o
>   Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"
>   upgrade . After editing my Vagrant file it worked perfectly

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct. Unfortunately a yes pip didn't do the trick this time but a quick search on how to "silently" install grub led me to this. DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade .  After editing my Vagrant file it worked perfectly

Comment: @MichaelSanford awesome, I'll update my answer with this solution.